# add restriction to sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this sql query:

```
SELECT players.tag, players.game_race, tournaments.region
FROM players
JOIN earnings ON players.player_id = earnings.player 
JOIN (SELECT player FROM earnings 
    where position = 1 group by player having count(player) > 2) 
    as DupPlayer on earnings.player=DupPlayer.player
JOIN tournaments ON earnings.tournament = tournaments.tournament_id
where earnings.position = 1 and tournaments.region is not NULL
ORDER BY players.player_id;
```

---

I want to get rid of every record that does not have a tag with `AM`, `EU`, and `Kr` region. Like if you look at the `creator` tag it only has the `Kr` region so I want to get rid of it. Same thing with `PartinG`since it only has the `Am` region.

```
+-------------+-----------+--------+
| tag         | game_race | region |
+-------------+-----------+--------+
| Leenock     | Z         | AM     |
| Leenock     | Z         | EU     |
| Leenock     | Z         | AM     |
| Leenock     | Z         | AM     |
| Leenock     | Z         | EU     |
| Leenock     | Z         | KR     |
| Creator     | P         | KR     |
| Creator     | P         | KR     |
| Life        | Z         | AM     |
| Life        | Z         | EU     |
| Life        | Z         | KR     |
| Life        | Z         | KR     |
| Life        | Z         | AM     |
| Life        | Z         | KR     |
| Life        | Z         | KR     |
| Life        | Z         | EU     |
| Life        | Z         | EU     |
| DongRaeGu   | Z         | KR     |
| DongRaeGu   | Z         | KR     |
| DongRaeGu   | Z         | KR     |
| DongRaeGu   | Z         | KR     |
| DongRaeGu   | Z         | EU     |
| DongRaeGu   | Z         | AM     |
| DongRaeGu   | Z         | AM     |
| DongRaeGu   | Z         | AM     |
| PartinG     | P         | AM     |
| TaeJa       | T         | KR     |
| TaeJa       | T         | EU     |
| TaeJa       | T         | AM     |
| TaeJa       | T         | KR     |
| TaeJa       | T         | EU     |
| TaeJa       | T         | KR     |
| TaeJa       | T         | EU     |
| TaeJa       | T         | KR     |
| TaeJa       | T         | EU     |
| TaeJa       | T         | KR     |
| TaeJa       | T         | EU     |
| TaeJa       | T         | KR     |
| TaeJa       | T         | KR     |
| TaeJa       | T         | KR     |
| TaeJa       | T         | KR     |
| TaeJa       | T         | KR     |
```

I thought this would work but it just caused a bunch of duplicates.

```
SELECT players.player_id, players.tag, players.game_race,
   earnings.tournament, earnings.player, earnings.position,
   tournaments.tournament_id, tournaments.region
FROM players
JOIN earnings ON players.player_id = earnings.player 
JOIN (SELECT player FROM earnings 
    where position = 1 group by player having count(player) > 2) 
    as DupPlayer on earnings.player=DupPlayer.player
JOIN (SELECT region FROM tournaments 
    group by region having count(region) > 2) 
    as DupPlayer1 on region=DupPlayer1.region
JOIN tournaments ON earnings.tournament = tournaments.tournament_id
where earnings.position = 1 and tournaments.region is not NULL
ORDER BY players.player_id;
```

---

Trying the suggestion. This doesn't seem to be working. It leaves Parting behind and SjoW which has all EU.

```
> SELECT players.tag, players.game_race, tournaments.region
    -> FROM players
    -> JOIN earnings ON players.player_id = earnings.player
    -> JOIN (SELECT player FROM earnings
    ->     where position = 1 group by player having count(player) > 2)
    ->     as DupPlayer on earnings.player=DupPlayer.player
    -> JOIN tournaments ON earnings.tournament = tournaments.tournament_id
    ->     and tournaments.region in ('AM', 'EU', 'KR')
    -> where earnings.position = 1 and tournaments.region is not NULL
    -> and players.tag in (
    ->   SELECT players.tag
    ->   FROM players
    ->   JOIN earnings ON players.player_id = earnings.player
    ->   JOIN (SELECT player FROM earnings
    ->       where position = 1 group by player having count(player) > 2)
    ->       as DupPlayer on earnings.player=DupPlayer.player
    ->   JOIN tournaments ON earnings.tournament = tournaments.tournament_id
    ->       and tournaments.region in ('AM', 'EU', 'KR')
    ->       group by players.tag
    ->       having count(distinct tournaments.region) = 3
    -> )
    -> ORDER BY players.player_id;
+------------+-----------+--------+
| tag        | game_race | region |
+------------+-----------+--------+
| Leenock    | Z         | AM     |
| Leenock    | Z         | AM     |
| Leenock    | Z         | AM     |
| Leenock    | Z         | EU     |
| Leenock    | Z         | EU     |
| Leenock    | Z         | KR     |
| Life       | Z         | AM     |
| Life       | Z         | AM     |
| Life       | Z         | EU     |
| Life       | Z         | EU     |
| Life       | Z         | KR     |
| Life       | Z         | KR     |
| Life       | Z         | KR     |
| Life       | Z         | KR     |
| Life       | Z         | EU     |
| DongRaeGu  | Z         | KR     |
| DongRaeGu  | Z         | KR     |
| DongRaeGu  | Z         | AM     |
| DongRaeGu  | Z         | AM     |
| DongRaeGu  | Z         | AM     |
| DongRaeGu  | Z         | KR     |
| DongRaeGu  | Z         | EU     |
| DongRaeGu  | Z         | KR     |
| PartinG    | P         | AM     |
| TaeJa      | T         | KR     |
| TaeJa      | T         | AM     |
| TaeJa      | T         | KR     |
| TaeJa      | T         | EU     |
| TaeJa      | T         | KR     |
| TaeJa      | T         | KR     |
| TaeJa      | T         | EU     |
| TaeJa      | T         | EU     |
| TaeJa      | T         | EU     |
| TaeJa      | T         | KR     |
| TaeJa      | T         | EU     |
| TaeJa      | T         | KR     |
| TaeJa      | T         | KR     |
| TaeJa      | T         | KR     |
| TaeJa      | T         | KR     |
| TaeJa      | T         | KR     |
| viOLet     | Z         | AM     |
| viOLet     | Z         | AM     |
| viOLet     | Z         | EU     |
| HerO       | P         | AM     |
| HerO       | P         | AM     |
| HerO       | P         | EU     |
| HerO       | P         | EU     |
| HerO       | P         | AM     |
| SjoW       | T         | EU     |
| SjoW       | T         | EU     |
| SjoW       | T         | EU     |
| SjoW       | T         | EU     |
| SjoW       | T         | EU     |
```

Answer (score 0):

If  you need  only the result with all the 3 region  'AM', 'EU', 'KR' 
you should filter for this result and check for the tag taht have all using a subquery with having  count(distinct region)=3

```
SELECT players.tag, players.game_race, tournaments.region
FROM players
JOIN earnings ON players.player_id = earnings.player 
JOIN (SELECT player FROM earnings 
    where position = 1 group by player having count(player) > 2) 
    as DupPlayer on earnings.player=DupPlayer.player
JOIN tournaments ON earnings.tournament = tournaments.tournament_id 
    and tournaments.region in ('AM', 'EU', 'KR')
where earnings.position = 1 and tournaments.region is not NULL
and players.tag in ( 
  SELECT players.tag
  FROM players
  JOIN earnings ON players.player_id = earnings.player 
  JOIN (SELECT player FROM earnings 
      where position = 1 group by player having count(player) > 2) 
      as DupPlayer on earnings.player=DupPlayer.player
  JOIN tournaments ON earnings.tournament = tournaments.tournament_id 
      and tournaments.region in ('AM', 'EU', 'KR')
      group by players.tag
      having count(distinct tournaments.region) = 3
)
ORDER BY players.player_i
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working. It leaves Parting behind and SjoW which has all EU.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the part you added:

```
JOIN (SELECT region FROM tournaments 
    group by region having count(region) > 2)
```

You have the right general idea but wrong detail.  Change the subquery to select only the players from the 3 regions you want.